# Cohomology groups of coherent sheaves for very small and very big twists.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, homology-cohomology, coherent-sheaves, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be nonzero coherent sheaf over the projective space $\mathbb{P}_k^n$.
The Serre vanishing Theorem says that $h^i \mathcal{F}(d)=0$ for $i>0$ and $d\gg 0$.

I am wondering if it is always true that $h^0 \mathcal{F}(d) \neq 0$ for $d \gg 0$, and if itn't, under which conditions can that be true.

In the same context, can we say that $h^n \mathcal{F}(d) \neq 0$ for $d \ll 0$? and if not, under which conditions can that be true.

Thank you.

Comment: Answering the question above will help to answer my previous question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032287/question-about-tate-resolution-and-cohomology-groups-of-nonzero-coherent-sheaves

Comment: This is true. Let $\mathcal{O}(1)$ be your very ample. Then, there exists some $m$ such that $\mathcal{O}(m)\otimes\mathcal{F}$ is globally generated. But, if $h^0\mathcal{F}(m)=0$, then global generation would imply that $\mathcal{F}(m)=0$, which would imply that $\mathcal{F}(m)\otimes\mathcal{O}(-m)=\mathcal{F}$ is zero.

Comment: Your other question should follow from the previous by applying Serre duality.

Comment: Thanks Alex for comments, I will follow them, but I have a question, is $m$ in your comment unique, and does $\mathcal{O}(m)\otimes \mathcal{F}$ globally generated implies that $\mathcal{O}(m+1) \otimes \mathcal{F}$ is globally generated. because one asks what if $m$ in your comment is less than $d$ for which $h^0\mathcal{F}(d)= 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by unique? And yes, $\mathcal{O}(m+1)\otimes\mathcal{F}$ is $(\mathcal{O}(m)\otimes\mathcal{F})\otimes\mathcal{O}(1)$, and the tensor product of globally generated sheaves are globally generated.

Comment: I searched it, and the theorem says there is $m_0$ such that for all $m \geq m_0$ we have $\mathcal{F}(m)= \mathcal{O}(m) \otimes \mathcal{F}$ is globally generated, and your answer is exactly that by induction. I wish that you recommend me a book to source to read how globally generating would imply that $\mathcal{F}(m)=0$.

Comment: Because if $\mathcal{G}$ is globally generated, there exists global sections $\{g_i\}$ such that $\{g_{i,p}\}$ generate $\mathcal{G}_p$ for all points $p$. So, if $\mathcal{G}$ is globally generated and $H^0(\mathcal{G})=0$, then the above shows that $\mathcal{G}_p=0$ for all $p$, so $\mathcal{G}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have this down as an answer.

Yes, such a $d$ does exist. Note since $\mathcal{O}(1)$ (the canonical very ample bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$) is ample, we know that there exists $d\geqslant 0$ such that $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d)$ is globally generated. Suppose that $h^0(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))=0$. Then, by the fact that $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d)$ is globally generated, we would have that $(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))_p=0$ for all $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$. Thus, $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d)=0$, and so

$$\mathcal{F}=(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))\otimes\mathcal{O}(-d)=0$$

contradictory to assumption. So, $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d)$ has non-zero global sections.

Now, we also want to show that there is $d\ll 0$ such that $h^n(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))\ne 0$. But, for any $d\leqslant 0$, we have that

$$H^n(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))\cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))^\vee\otimes\mathcal{O}(-n-1))^\vee$$
by Serre duality (since $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}=\mathcal{O}(-n-1)$). Since $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is a line bundle, we have an isomorphism

$$(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))^\vee\cong \mathcal{F}^\vee\otimes\mathcal{O}(-d)$$

and so

$$H^n(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{O}(d))\cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{F}^\vee\otimes\mathcal{O}(-d-n-1))^\vee$$

Since $\mathcal{F}^\vee$ is still coherent, the first part shows that for $d\ll 0$, this right hand side will be non-zero, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

There is another nice answer to the first statement, For $d\gg 0$ we have $$p_\mathcal{F}(d)= h^0 \mathcal{F}(d)$$ where $p_\mathcal{F}(d)$ is the Hilbert polynomial.

So the cohomology groups for very large twists should be nonzero because Hilbert polynomial can't have infinitely many roots. and the proof of the second claim is as the answer above.